# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException on code commit in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, code-injection

I am trying to commit injected code in function of java project.

```
iCompilationUnit.applyTextEdit(rewriter.rewriteAST(), new NullProgressMonitor());
iCompilationUnit.commitWorkingCopy(true, new NullProgressMonitor());
```

However I am getting the error

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

on first line.

Comment: Debug it! Separate out the statements, assigning the results to variables, and see which one of the three is causing the error: `applyTextEdit()`, `rewriteAST()`, or `new NullProgressMonitor()`. Then post the more detailed information.

Comment: rewriter.rewriteAST() got exception of java.lang.StackOverflowError